# How to select distinct records based on multiple row values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE event
  uuid character varying(50),
  created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  event_type character varying(50))
```

And the data is like this

[image]

I need to fetch the latest event_type that is 'NotSaved' or 'Saved' per uuid 
Like in this case uuid_1234, Saved and uuid_1235, NotSaved.
I tried with distinct, subquery and max but didn't give correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from      
 (
  select *,row_number() over(partition by uuid order by createdtimestamp desc) rn
 from event
) a where a.rn=1
```

and below also work

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (uuid ) 
    uuid , createdtimestamp 
FROM event
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: what does a.rn=1 do?

Comment: @user1298426 it will return the last event row  per uuid basis

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to join the table with itself.
First, create the select statement to pull out the uuid and the latest created date specifying the required event types.

```
select uuid, max(created)
from event
where event_type in ('NotSaved', 'Saved')
```

Notice we can't get the event_type column (or any additional columns) in this statement. Only the uuid, and the max of created.

Then, using this select statement as an "inline table", join the event table to it to get the remaining columns.

```
select distinct e.uuid, e.created, e.event_type
from event e
inner join (select uuid, max(created)
            from event
            where event_type in ('NotSaved', 'Saved')) maxe
on e.uuid = maxe.uuid and e.created = maxe.created;
```

We give the inline table an alias, maxe, since it doesn't actually exist and we need a way to refer to it.  The alias e, for the event table is just for convenience, it makes the join condition easier to type and read.